# Scientific linux: How to install yum using rpm?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, scientific-linux

On Scientific linux 6.0(RH like linux) 
I accidentally removed python, so yum removed as well.µ

How to install yum with rpm?

**EDIT**

I try to install python but it is somehow looped the dependences:

```
rpm -Uvh http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-libs-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
    Retrieving http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-libs-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
    error: Failed dependencies:
            python = 2.6.5-3.el6 is needed by python-libs-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64
```

Then:

```
 rpm -Uvh http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python
-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the package(s) and type `rpm -Uvh <packagenames>` as root or `sudo rpm -Uvh <packagenames>` as normal user

I used `rpm -qpR yum-3.2.27-14.el6.noarch.rpm` to get a list of dependencies for yum, hope that gets all off them in one go:

Download all the packages with the following code block:

```
wget http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-libs-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/pygpgme-0.1-18.20090824bzr68.el6.x86_64.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-7.el6.noarch.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/python-pycurl-7.19.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/rpm-python-4.8.0-12.el6.x86_64.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/yum-3.2.27-14.el6.noarch.rpm \
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-14.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Install them as follows:

```
rpm -Uhv py*.rpm \
   yum*.rpm \
   rpm-py*.rpm
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that if the OP managed to uninstall yum(?!?), they probably need a bit of guidance as to the required contents of `<packagename>`.

Comment: he won't learn if there is no pain ;)

Comment: working on expanding the answer to be a bit more helpful..

Comment: Thenks for replay,but your workaround does not help, see my edit.

Comment: @Arman, give me a minute, trying to account for all your lost packages

Comment: @Arman try the extras I added

Comment: Nice it works!! only I you should add to your rpm lists the python-pycurl-7.19.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm.

Comment: I added the URL

Comment: But I don't even have wget on this openjdk:18-jdk-oraclelinux8 docker image. No wget, no apt, no yum, no apk.